# Basic Clojure: how do I flatten a nested list?

Tags: clojure

Please look at the following code:

```
(def data {:color ["R", "B", "G"] :name "Hello" :up "down"})

(defn collapse-vector-kvp [k v] 
   (map #(hash-map k %) v))

(defn collapse-map [m]
   (map #(let 
      [x %] 
      (if (vector? (val x)) 
            (collapse-vector-kvp (key x) (val x))
            (hash-map (key x) (val x))
        )) m))

(collapse-map data)

=> ({:name "Hello"} ({:color "R"} {:color "B"} {:color "G"}) {:up "down"})
```

What I would like to do is create a single list, rather than have the 'color' entries be in a list within the list. Is this easily achievable?

Comment: I like how your question contains the answer. :)

Comment: @IvanKoblik even better, title of question contains the answer :)

Comment: Haha, I changed the title so that it was more search friendly :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
user=> (def data2 '({:name "Hello"} ({:color "R"} {:color "B"} {:color "G"}) {:up "down"}))
#'user/data2
user=> (flatten data2)
({:name "Hello"} {:color "R"} {:color "B"} {:color "G"} {:up "down"})
```

Answer (score 2):

Another version of `collapse-map`:

```
(defn collapse-map [m]
  (let [sep-m (group-by (comp vector? val) m)]
    (concat (map (fn [[k v]] {k v}) 
                 (sep-m false))
            (apply concat (map (fn [[k v]] 
                                 (collapse-vector-kvp k v)) 
                               (sep-m true))))))

(def test-data {:color ["R" "B" "G"] 
                :name "Hello" 
                :k ["v1" "v2" "v3"] 
                :up "down"})

(collapse-map test-data)
=> ({:name "Hello"}
    {:up "down"}
    {:color "R"}
    {:color "B"}
    {:color "G"}
    {:k "v1"}
    {:k "v2"}
    {:k "v3"})
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a benefit to doing it this way? (More idiomatic?)

Comment: @acron This version just does the job explicitly without `flatten`-ing final result.